# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Inline Form with labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After searching everywhere i couldnt see exactly how i can design an inline form that has the following design: (using bootstrap 3 classes instead of css customizations when possible)

When the user has a wide screen:

```
 Form-Legend

     LabelFieldA: InputFieldA   LabelFieldB: InputFieldB   LabelFieldC: InputFieldC   <Submit Button>
```

When the user has a smaller screen:

```
Form-Legend

    LabelFieldA: InputFieldA   LabelFieldB: InputFieldB   

    LabelFieldC: InputFieldC   <Submit Button>
```

The idea is that the design initially puts all the fields in one line and if it doesnt fit the controls would jump to the next line, but maintaining the Label + Field together.

Also if there is a way so the spacing between each Label + Input is greater than the spacing between the Label and its Field.

And lastly if there is a way of having more vertical margin between the Label + Field when it jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## Option #1 : fixed columns

You can use a structure mixing `col-xs-12`, `col-sm-6` and `col-lg-3` to get 1, 2 or 4 columns. Inside your `form-group`, remember to fix label/input sizes with `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8` :

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form form-inline" role="form">

    <legend>Form legend</legend>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="InputFieldA" class="col-xs-4">Field A</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldA" placeholder="InputFieldA">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="InputFieldB" class="col-xs-4">Field B</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldB" placeholder="InputFieldB">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="InputFieldC" class="col-xs-4">Field C</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldC" placeholder="InputFieldC">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">Submit Button</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

You still need a few CSS :

```
// get a larger input, and align it with submit button
.form-inline .form-group > div.col-xs-8 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
// vertical align label
.form-inline label {
    line-height: 34px;
}
// force inline control to fit container width
// http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline
.form-inline .form-control {
    width: 100%;
}
// Reset margin-bottom for our multiline form
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

You can add as many inputs as you want.

[image]

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/116274)

## Option #2 : fluid columns

To be able to not care of the number of fields per row, you can use this structure :

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form form-inline form-multiline" role="form">

    <legend>Form legend</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="InputFieldA">Field A</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldA" placeholder="InputFieldA">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="InputFieldB">Very Long Label For Field B</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldB" placeholder="InputFieldB">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="InputFieldC">F. C</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldC" placeholder="InputFieldC">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="InputFieldD">Very Long Label For Field D</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldD" placeholder="InputFieldD">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="InputFieldE">Very Long Label For Field E</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldE" placeholder="InputFieldE">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="InputFieldF">Field F</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldF" placeholder="InputFieldF">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

And a few CSS lines to fix margins :

```
.form-multiline .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.form-multiline label,
.form-multiline .form-control {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

[image]

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/116542)

Comment: Isnt there a way so i wouldnt have to foresee the number of items it will fit in each row? Also if i try to make the Submit Button smaller it disaligns from the rest of fields

Comment: For submit button : make col + offset + push equal to 12 : `col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4`, or `col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8`, etc... To get an automatic grid, see my edit.

Comment: You sir, are a wizard :). The second option was just what i was looking for. As a note, i saw that the 'form' class is not present in bootstrap 3. Also now i have to set custom css widths for the controls, as the col-xs classes uses % widths that dont work in your 2º bootply. I will use the second example with some changes: http://www.bootply.com/117291 suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions about ? You seems to follow the right ptah ! I would just avoid the double `col-xs-offset-1` (in fact, I would use `col-sm-offset-1` instead, to get more space on mobile devices). And you shouldn't use `control-label` if you want your labels to float near your inputs.

Comment: Thanks, the offset is meaningful when combined with the rest of the our web. I used control-label so i could style them specifically, in case we end having some extra label next to an input or replacing one (for readonly info fields)

Comment: I copied one of the form groups and pasted it into my form, yet it still appears on different lines. Why?

Comment: Great answer.  Any ideas for if you want to make a double column (ie a textarea) with the first solution?  Ideally the label would line up and the right side of the text box would as well.  Simply changing to xs-12 and 2, 10 column widths gets you close but it's not exact.

Answer (score 5):

The same as option #1 from @zessx, but without overriding CSS. This one also aligns labels to the right to increase space between label-control pairs. Class "media" is there to add top margin without creating a custom class, but in general case it is better to have a custom one.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <legend>Form legend</legend>
    <div class="media col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="InputFieldA" class="control-label text-right col-xs-4">Field A</label>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldA" placeholder="InputFieldA">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="InputFieldB" class="control-label text-right col-xs-4">Field B</label>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldB" placeholder="InputFieldB">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="InputFieldC" class="control-label text-right col-xs-4">Field C</label>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFieldC" placeholder="InputFieldC">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">Submit Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/UnBZXGwjcj)

Answer (score 2):

I would propose something completely different, wrap the labels and fields inside inline divs:

```
<div style="display:inline-block"> 
  Label:input
</div>
```

This way, when they are about to break, they break in pairs, labels+inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I played with the grid system and this is as close as I could get to your setup.

```
<div class="container">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This has two fields only. You might want to change the `col` classes to fit your layout.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuQh9/1/)

Comment: But in your example if i adjust the width of the window the 2º label + input doesnt jump to the line below. Take into account that it could have 3, 4 or even more pairs of labels + input that have to adjust to one or more lines depending on the available width.

Comment: As as I said you will have to adjust the `col` classes to fit the number of elements. You won't be able to create something so dynamic with bootstrap only. You will have to resort to some JavaScript or custom CSS in order to achieve that.

Comment: My closest attempts where with http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline instead of col classes as you dont have to define the number of elements there will be in each row...the problem is getting the labels + input together after jumping to the next row and aligning them in following rows correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

**Working here- http://www.bootply.com/117807**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3 col-sm-4"><label>First Name</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-9 col-sm-8"><input type="text"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3 col-sm-4"><label>Last Name</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-9 col-sm-8"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3 col-sm-4"><label>Contact</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-9 col-sm-8"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put both label and text input in cols div. Hope this will save time for all others :)

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-right">
   <label>City</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 text-right">
     <asp:TextBox data-toggle="tooltip" pbpo-validation-type="required" title="City" runat="server" ID="textbox_city" CssClass="form-control input-sm" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder=""></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```