# Twitter Bootstrap .col on a <label>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using Twitter Bootstrap two columns, each 12 columns wide when viewed on an `xs` device, render themselves on one line:

```
<label for="contact" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Preferred Contact Method:</label>
<label for="telephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
  <small><em>Telephone</em></small>
</label>
```

When viewed on a small mobile the columns should expand to effectively `col-xs-12` each; however, both items are shown next to each other suggesting this is not the case. What's even more curious is that another item, say of `col-sm-2`, does appear on the next line.

The above problem and correct functionality can be achieved via wrapping either `<label>` in a `<div>`. I was under the impression that the class `col-*` can be used on any element; however, perhaps I have understood this wrong as applying it to a `<label>` does not produce the expected results, that is, the `<label>` does not expand to fill the `row` unless it comes after/follows a `<div>`.

Is my understanding incorrect or is something else at play?

Comment: you can add the column classes to pretty much everything. Keep in mind thought that the nesting is done properly. Perhaps this link can help you some more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935933/twitter-bootstrap-3-inline-form-with-labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was under the impression that the class `col-*` can be used on any element

Yes, in general you can use the `col-*` classes on almost any element – but without a `row` element around them, you might not get the expect results. (For example, `.row` includes a negative margin on the left and right side, to counter the padding between the columns that produces the “gutter” between them.)

However, for your specific problem here, you can solve that in two ways.
Either add `col-xs-12` class on both of them – that will apply `width:100%`, and make them go across the whole width on small screens.
Or add `label { display:block; }`, that will make them take full width as well – by default, they are inline elements.

Comment: Thanks. I know I could add `col-xs-12`; however, I was under the impression that Bootstrap is mobile first and therefore if nothing is specified for `xs` sized devices then it assumes an element is `col-xs-12`. Clearly, it does not do that except perhaps on `<div>` elements.

Comment: Without the `col-xs-12` class, no extra formatting at all is applied to the element on small screens. And as I said, `label` is by default an inline element, so it takes up only the space its content needs. If you don’t want to add the bootstrap class, then as I said applying `display:block` via your own stylesheet will work as well.

Comment: Part of my reply to you I have put in the reply in the other post. I have not asked how to solve the problem, as like I said in the question I had already solved it by wrapping one of them in a `<div>`; however, I believe your comment about the `<label>` being an inline element perhaps being the key. However, it doesn't explain why having no `col-xs` specified renders a block-level element as full screen width but an inline element not. Any thoughts?

Comment: _“it doesn't explain why having no col-xs specified renders a block-level element as full screen width”_ – block elements just take the full width by default.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is what I think you want:

```css
.control-label{
    background:#00F;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="contact" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-6 control-label">Preferred Contact Method:</label>
<label for="telephone" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-6 control-label">
  <small><em>Telephone</em></small>
</label>
```

It is full-width on very small devices (less than 768px) - that is **col-xs** - one quarter-width on small devices (between 768px and 992px) - that is **col-sm** - and half-width on any device larger than that - that is **col-md**.

If I got it wrong, just say to update my answer.
If it helps, +1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I knew I could add `col-xs-12` to solve the problem, nevertheless, I was under the impression that Bootstrap is mobile first and therefore if nothing is specified for `xs` sized devices then it assumes an element is `col-xs-12`. Clearly, it does not do that except perhaps on `<div>` elements, at least it does not hold true for `<label>` elements.

Comment: No. It is not a mobile first framework, **you** have to specify if you want some element to behave that way. I am glad I could help. Accepting the answer would be nice. Or a + :)

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpreting their [website](http://getbootstrap.com/) but it says: _Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, **mobile first** projects on the web._ It also says [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) that it is **Mobile First** in the third heading down. Finally, in the media queries section it says the `xs` is default. On a [tutorial page](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system) it also says _We don’t have to define anything for extra small devices since the default is one column._ Thoughts?

Comment: But a label is inline-block, if bootstrap made the inline-block elements full-width(or any other width) buttons and spans would look full-width (meaning horrible and unwanted).