# Cannot get my bootstrap rows on the same line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I read the other questions that were similar but my issue is more basic. I'm rather new to bootstrap but I'm testing it out to see if this will work for a simple form that I need to be opened by phones, tablets, and any other device.

I'm trying to get my textbox on the same line as the text that describes it. Instead, the textbox is under the text.

Here is what is happening:

[image]

Here is the cshtml page of the above:

```
@model  MvcBootstrap.Models.HomeModels.VisitingCustomer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="">
    <p class="lead">Please enter your branch number, account number, and at least the first three characters of your last name or at least the first three characters of your company name below so we can locate your account.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">

  @using (Html.BeginForm("TypeOfPayment", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Account Lookup</h2>

      <div class=".col-md-4">
        Branch Number
      </div>

      <div class=".col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Branch, new {@class = "", @maxlength = "2"})
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input id="submitpayment" class="typicalbutton" type="submit" value="Continue" />
    </div>

  }

</div>
```

I have no additional css code nor have I modified any of the existing css.

This should be pretty straight forward but I'm just not grasping the concept I guess. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have made an error putting a dot character in value of class atrributes. Don't use class=".col-md-4", use class="col-md-4" instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Inline Form with labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935933/twitter-bootstrap-3-inline-form-with-labels)

Comment: @AndrewB Yup, look right past that too. That worked! tyvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the Branch Number and the text box in one column like so

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <label for="branch-number">Branch Number</label>
   # add text box here and give it an id="branch-number"
</div>
```

Also, you don't need to have a `.` before the class name in your classes.

Comment: ty! something so simple that I overlooked.

Comment: Always happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this format. form-inline class makes the form inline. you don't need to use the responsive column classes. also you should use `class="col-md-*"` not `class=".col-md-*"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
     
    <label for="branch">  Branch Number</label>
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="branch no">
 </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can specify the class for different screen
 i.e
 col-lg-1 to col-lg-12 for large screen
 col-md-1 to col-md-12 for desktop / laptop screen
 col-sm-1 to col-sm-12 for tablet screen
 col-xs-1 to col-xs-12 for mobile screen

 Example

<input type="text" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an [inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TypeOfPayment", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-inline" }))
{
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Account Lookup</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Branch)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Branch, new {@class = "form-control", @maxlength = "2"})
            </div>
            <input id="submitpayment" class="typicalbutton" type="submit" value="Continue" />                
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In your model for this form you will want to add a `[DisplayName]` attribute for your Branch property so that you can use the `Html.LabelFor()` helper I included above:

```
[DisplayName("Branch Number")]
public string Branch { get; set; }
```

You will also want to read more about the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).  Your original code did not use the proper classes for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Asif Raza said, you should specify what size of screen are targeting. Keep in mind that the sizing will work for the size you specify and UP. So if you specify a medium size screen, it will affect medium size screens and larger, not smaller. 

I dont think thats your issue though, I think whats happening with you is there are extra margins you are not seeing that is causing the textbox to be placed below. The max width of the container is going to be 12 columns, which you are using, but if there are any other margins in between it's going to cause the textbox to fall below. I recommend inspecting the element with F12 to zone in and see if there is anything extra being added.